# Should I treat the dependent variable as count variable?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, count-data, continuous-data

In a study of crowdfunding, I am investigating the effect of the `reputation` of a person seeking funding for a project (a continuous variable) and `funding success.`

I am exploring two possibilities for a measure of funding success:

1. the `proportion of funding goal received` (i.e., funding received/funding goal*100); or
2. the `amount of funding received`.

My first doubt concerns whether one of the measures is more right/appropriate in a regression analysis than the other. Of course, in either case, I would be controlling for `funding goal`.

[image]

[image]

A second question is whether I should treat the `amount of funding` as count variable (all are integers in my dataset and range from USD 0 to nearly  USD 50,000). If so, I understand I should be using a `Poisson/Negative binomilal/Zero inflation` models and not a linear model.

Comment: No, funding is probably a dollar (or euro ...) amount, and monetary amounts are measured, not counted. There is no reason to expect count distributions like poisson

Comment: The normality tests of linear model (lm) with funding received as dependent variable however fail. I have tried transformations, but with not much change.

Comment: Well, that the response is not normal doesn't say much ---- many other possibilities. Can you show us a histogram? Maybe look into generalized linear models, with for instance gamma distribution --- or ...

Comment: Histogram of funding received suggests it is is a right-skewed data.

Comment: That is unsurprising! Can you show us (include the plot as an edit to the Q) the histogram?

Comment: What is perhaps most crucial is that a logarithmic link makes sense for amount given that the outcome cannot be negative and that (I guess) heteroscedasticity is likely too. The arguments at https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/ are noteworthy. Getting the functional form about right is more crucial than what the distribution family might be. I don't comment on amount or proportion: they are different answers to different questions.

Comment: Have added histograms @kjetilbhalvorsen.

Comment: Your maximum for proportion is $\gg 100$ from which I infer that possibly funding received $\gg$ funding goal. Understood, but then the term _proportion_ makes no sense. You just have a ratio there.

Comment: Yes, you are right @NickCox. So given the ratio dependent variable, what would you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: The ratio is unbounded just like the amount, but if people's goals can differ then the analyses of amount and ratio are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Q in title:  No, monetary amounts are measured, not counted, so there is no reason to expect a count variable distribution like the Poisson.

Otherwise, your histograms are quite skewed, but in itself says little about a distribution model, since they show the marginal distribution, not the conditional distribution which is the one you want to model. As said in comments, a generalized linear model with a log link might make sense.